# Octave: how can these FOR loops be vectorized?

Tags: matlab, recursion, octave, vectorization

I am writing an Octave script to calculate the price of an European option.

The first part uses Monte Carlo to simulate the underlying asset price over n number of time periods. This is repeated nIter number of times.

Octave makes it very easy to setup initial matrices. But I haven't found the way to complete the task in a vectorized way, avoiding FOR loops:

```
%% Octave simplifies creation of 'e', 'dlns', and 'Prices'
e = norminv(rand(nIter,n));
dlns = cat(2, ones(nIter,1), exp((adj_r+0.5*sigma^2)*dt+sigma*e.*sqrt(dt)));
Prices = zeros(nIter, n+1);

for i = 1:nIter              % IS THERE A WAY TO VECTORIZE THESE FOR LOOPS?
  for j = 1:n+1
    if j == 1
      Prices(i,j)=S0;
    else
      Prices(i,j)=Prices(i,j-1)*dlns(i,j);
    end
  endfor
endfor
```

Note that the price in n is equal to price in n-1 times a factor, hence the following does not work...

```
Prices(i,:) = S0 * dlns(i,:)
```

...since it takes S0 and multiplies it by all the factors, yielding different results than the expected random walk.

Comment: Typical values for `nIter,n,adj_r,sigma,dt,S0`?

Comment: nIter: 100,000; n: 100; adj_r = 0.03 ; sigma = 0.2; dt =  1/n; S0 = 60

Comment: Although for what I've read, size of the matrix influences the solution. Read a great post timing different solutions where yo took part! nIter = 100,000 and n = 100 are usually used for final solutions, whereas nIter = 1,000 and n = 25 are used for intermediate tests...I mention this in case there are different solutions for different matrix scales...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the dependency between iterations to obtain results for each new column with respect to the previous column, it seems you would need at least one loop there, but do all operations within a column in a vectorized fashion and that might speed it up for you. The *vectorized* replacement for the two nested loops would look something like this -

```
Prices(:,1)=S0;
for j = 2:n+1
    Prices(:,j) = Prices(:,j-1).*dlns(:,j);
endfor
```

It just occurred to me that the dependency can be taken care of with [`cumprod`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumprod.html) that gets us `cumulative product` which is essentially being done here and thus would lead to a no-loop solution! Here's the implementation -

```
Prices = [repmat(S0,nIter,1) cumprod(dlns(:,2:end),2)*S0]
```

---

### Benchmarking on MATLAB

Benchmarking Code -

```
%// Parameters as told by OP and then create the inputs
nIter= 100000;
n = 100;
adj_r = 0.03;
sigma = 0.2;
dt = 1/n;
S0 = 60;
e = norminv(rand(nIter,n));
dlns = cat(2, ones(nIter,1), exp((adj_r+0.5*sigma^2)*dt+sigma*e.*sqrt(dt)));

disp('-------------------------------------- With Original Approach')
tic
Prices = zeros(nIter, n+1);
for i = 1:nIter
    for j = 1:n+1
        if j == 1
            Prices(i,j)=S0;
        else
            Prices(i,j)=Prices(i,j-1)*dlns(i,j);
        end
    end
end
toc, clear Prices

disp('-------------------------------------- With Proposed Approach - I')
tic
Prices2(nIter, n+1)=0; %// faster pre-allocation scheme
Prices2(:,1)=S0;
for j = 2:n+1
    Prices2(:,j)=Prices2(:,j-1).*dlns(:,j);
end
toc, clear Prices2

disp('-------------------------------------- With Proposed Approach - II')
tic
Prices3 = [repmat(S0,nIter,1) cumprod(dlns(:,2:end),2)*S0];
toc, clear Prices3
```

Runtimes results -

```
-------------------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 0.259054 seconds.
-------------------------------------- With Proposed Approach - I
Elapsed time is 0.020566 seconds.
-------------------------------------- With Proposed Approach - II
Elapsed time is 0.067292 seconds.
```

Now, the runtimes do suggest that the first proposed approach might be a better fit here!

Comment: Works like a charm! It cut the time to execute 100,000 iterations from 45sec to 4 sec. Thanks!

Comment: @user194145 Added benchamrking code that gets us the speedups and also note the modified pre-allocation scheme in it! Awesome results you got by the way!

Comment: JIT has to be kicking in in your MATLAB...there is no way I get less that 25 secs with original approach on my Octave. Thanks again!

Comment: @user194145 Or could be that I got lots of RAM ;)